# sudo ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa return error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, sudo

I m trying to save ssh authentication with the command `ssh-add` for sudo usage:

```
linux$ sudo ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

but as indicated it returns error

I made some research and I found that I have to to execute the command `eval "ssh-agent -s"` as indicated in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/17695338#17695338

But I got error if execute it with sudo command

```
$ sudo eval `ssh-agent -s`
sudo: eval: command not found
```

What I m missing?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Why do you use sudo?

Answer (score 1):

From the following [link](http://petrkout.com/linux/ssh-agent-forwarding-to-sudo-root-user/):

Fortunately, there is a way to solve this problem. Sudo has a configuration option that allows to keep given environmental variables from the user issuing the sudo command. The options is called env_keep and can be configured by changing the settings in /etc/sudoers files as follows (always use visudo to edit the file):

```
visudo

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults>root    env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

In other words,  add the line keeping the SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable below the Defaults     env_reset line. Then save the file and run

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add
```

and you should be able to execute a sudo command that accesses your server using the non-sudo user’s key without being asked for the key passphrase.